# Adding Massive amount of Articles to existing publication cause screen to hang forever

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I am using Win Server 2008 R2 / SQL Server 2008 R2 and i am trying to add about 2K + articles to the existing publication and the screen hangs @ the articles screen.

The screen has been there and hanged since 12 hours ago .

Based on the server spec : 256GB Ram with loads of core and threads, running on SSD/SAS.

it's highly unlikely due to hardware, it has to be due to some bug in the software.

When such scenario happens, what should I do to rectify or analyze the problem ?

Update :

Did some script via `sp_addarticle` but it still takes around 40 seconds per article.

I in fact have over 6k articles.

Sample script I used :

```
   EXEC Sp_addarticle 
              @publication = 'DB_live_Pub', 
              @article = N'vw_AuditLog', 
              @source_owner = N'dbo', 
              @source_object = N'vw_AuditLog', 
              @type = N'view schema only', 
              @description = NULL, 
              @creation_script = NULL, 
              @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', 
              @schema_option = 0x0000000008000001, 
              @destination_table = N'vw_AuditLog', 
              @destination_owner = N'dbo'
```

Update 2 :

I killed the job, stop all related agents, drop all publications, drop all subscriptions, 
Recreated new subscription from scratch. Surprisingly, everything speeds up fast. I managed to create 5k+ Articles in 2 hours. After that i proceed with the snapshot, after some error debugging, managed to create a snapshot.

Now i am creating a subscription to the publisher.

Comment: You may want to try adding the articles via script, i.e. sp_addarticle.  Does it still hang then?

Comment: Do you have example script for views and user defined function ? It's a little complicated for me .

Comment: sp_addarticle (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173857.aspx) has the parameter list and definitions, as well as an example. The type parameter will depend on the type of view for views and type will be func schema only for user defined functions I think.  To be sure, you can walk through the New Publication Wizard and only select 1 or a few articles of a specific type and at the end of the wizard there is an option Generate a script file with steps to create the publication. Generate the script and inspect the sp_addarticle calls for the exact parameters.

Comment: Another option is to use the New Publication Wizard to create the publication but only select a few articles.  Then go back to the Publication Properties, right-click the publication -> Properties, and then add the remaining articles a few at a time, i.e. like 100 hundred at a time.

Comment: i generated the script via New Publication Wizard . Did some coding and generated the rest of the scripts. 
now running over 1.8k views for replication.
fingers crossed.

Comment: Maximum Capacity Specifications say this number of articles is possible for a Transactional Publication so it should work (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx#Replication).  Good luck my friend.

Comment: If everything checks out, post your solution as the answer for future visitors.

Comment: it's running now but at a rate of 40 seconds per article, i m just doing replication for view. Estimated to finish is 0.9 day. 

It's still too slow.

Comment: Is there any activity on the published tables/views? You may want to try adding the articles during a time of low user activity.

Comment: I managed to create the snapshot. During subscription, the job fails because it's unable to replicate the view which has nested views.